# Specify controller for Ember.js template render helper programmatically?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

The case is I want my `{{render}}` to infer a controller name from supplied ember-data model's name automatically.

e.g. in `{{render 'animal' animal}}`, if `animal` is a `Cat`, I hope the template is rendered with a `CatController`

It seems that the render helper accepts a `controller=` parameter now, but then regards the parameter as a literal instead of a variable.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing-handlebars/lib/helpers/render.js#L115

For now, I just put the representation codes (needed by template) in target models, which I believe is bad.

What is the right way to implement this polymorphic-alike rendering?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are describing is exactly what ember does, as described here http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers

```
{{render 'animal' animal}}
```

will render the animal template, with the Animal model, AnimalController controller and AnimalView view, if they exist.

Comment: That's a very nice function for ember, but what I need is to render with another controller other than `animal`, which is a subclass of `AnimalController` and knows how to convert the `animal`(model, not knowing how to act like an animal) to an `animal`(Controller)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an alternative to the render helper, where you can specify everything you need.

```
this.render('TEMPLATENAME', {
    into: 'TEMPLATE/LAYOUT',
    outlet: 'OUTLET NAME IN TEMPLATE',
    controller : 'CONTROLLER NAME FOR CURRENT TEMPLATE',  /*  optional  */
    model : 'MODEL NAME FOR CURRENT TEMPLATE',   /* optional  */ 
});
```

You can add it directly from your route in the renderTemplate function

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){ },
    renderTemplate: function(){

        this._super();   /* Add it to prevent weird behaviour */

        this.render('header', {
           into: 'application',
           outlet: 'header',
           controller: 'headerMenu',
        )};

    },

});
```